# Reference a different table within a SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to MySQL and I don't get all the advanced uses.
Will this work or is there another way to achieve this?

I have 2 tables, Clients and ClientLog, Clients have a primany key of type INT and ClientLog stores that INT value as a foreign key, but it doesn't store the clients name, so when I want to display the client log I need to get the clients name form the CLIENTS table.

```
SELECT
    Log_Number
    ,(
        SELECT 
            Client_Name
        FROM Clients
        Where Client_ID = Log_Client
     ) AS Log_Client
    ,Log_SalesNumber
    ,Log_ProjectNumber
    ,Log_JobType
    ,Log_Date
FROM ClientLog
```

I want to display the entire ClientLog Table.

Comment: `JOIN` is the keyword you are looking for. Happy searching :)

Comment: @Cid Thanks, looked at the document now, its what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT

    Log_Number
    ,Client_Name
    ,Log_SalesNumber
    ,Log_ProjectNumber
    ,Log_JobType
    ,Log_Date

FROM ClientLog left outer join Clients on ClientLog.ClientLog = 
Clients.Log_Client
```

Comment: You might want to explain what the code does and why it solves the problem.